# Is there any way to update table rows based on other rows values in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a table like below

[image]

If CC date is in between checkIN and CheckOut date of same Ref No of other rows we need to updare CheckIn and CheckOut date to that CCDate. Like below

[image]

Could you please help me on this

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could use window functions:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        t.*,
        min(checkin) over(partition by refno) min_checkin,
        max(checkout) over(partition by refno) max_checkout
    from mytable t
) 
update cte 
set checkin = min_checkin, checkout = max_checkout
where ccdate between min_checkin and max_checkout
```

Note that this implicitly assumes that each `refno` has only one `checkin` and `checkout` value.

Comment: We need to check each ccdate is in between all checkIn and CheckOut date ranges for same reference number. we have multiple date ranges and we need to check CCdate to each and every date range if it is in one of the date range then we need to update those checkin and Checkout dates for that patticular CCdate

Comment: @Jayanth: yes. As far as concerned, that's what the query does. Are you able to test the query against your dataset?

Comment: I have tested but it updating data like min checkin and Max checkout dates. But here my concern first CCdate is need to check with remaining date range if it is satisfy one with one condition we need to update same Checkin and Checkout date range to that particular CCdate